# How do I insert multiple records from array in mySQL using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I have a look-up table:

```
CREATE TABLE technologies (
    technologyName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I want to store a new record in this table for every element in an array:

```
var values = ['Grunt', 'Gulp'];
```

So that the resulting table will look like:

```
+----------------+
| technologyName |
+----------------+
| Grunt          |
+----------------+
| Gulp           |
+----------------+
```

How can I do this using Node?

**Update:**

I know I can do something like this:

```
var values = [
  [
    ['Grunt'], 
    ['Something']
  ]
]
connection.query('INSERT IGNORE INTO technologies (technologyName) VALUES ?', values);
```

I tried this with the original array but it does not work. How can I convert the simple array into the more complicated one?

Comment: @MelissaAvery-Weir No, I do not **need** do do that. I made the choice to keep the question short and sweet for anyone who might stumble upon it in the future.

Comment: Nope, you certainly don't *need* to (i.e., the question is unlikely to be closed). I should have said "your question will be more highly voted and more readily answered if you include what you've tried" (per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That all said, thanks for adding the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple things at once...

From the mysql docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

so for you:

```
insert into technologies (technologyname) values ('grunt'),('gulp')
```

---

```
var sql = "insert into technologies (technologyname) values ";

for(var v in values)
  sql += "('" + connection.escape(values[v]) + "'),";

sql = sql.substr(0,sql.length-1); // take off the last comma since we added one after each value
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using `?` e.g. `INSERT IGNORE INTO technologies (technologyName) VALUES ?`?

Comment: @Angularnoob I'm pretty sure you can't insert multiple rows from a multi-value parameter (unfortunately!)

Comment: Ah, OK. I am afraid, by the way, that your code does not work, presumably because there is no comma?

Comment: @Angularnoob, yep, didn't have a comma between the values.. fixed in the comment now.  I add a comma after each item, then take the last character off of the whole sql to get rid of the extra comma

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use "?" to escape your values and avoid SQL injections, mysqljs accept nested arrays for bulk inserts.
So the answer to your update is :

```
var valuesNestedArray  = [];

for(var v in values ) {
  valuesNestedArray.push([values[v]]);
}

var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO technologies (technologyname) values ?";
connection.query(sql, [valuesNestedArray], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;   
});
```